# Reference # 240326-017888: How can I retrieve organization id via LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to implement a company look up via LinkedIn API in our software. The interface is very similar to the "Issuing organization" look up of LinkedIn's Add Certificate to Profile feature. So users can type in the keywords to find a company with its organization id information.

Here is what I have done:

1. I have set up a LinkedIn developer account create one App. And I have the Client ID, Client Secret and retrieved an active access token via OAuth 2.0 tools.
2. When I use "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations?q=vanityName&vanityName=LinkedIn" as an example to retrieve the organization information. I basically want to know what is the organization id. The response is success, but the response result JSON is not the organization information. It includes html content but there is no organization id.

What I expect the response result is similar to what is stated in this API document: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/organizations/organization-lookup-api?view=li-lms-2024-02&tabs=http#schema](https://stackoverflow.com)

Do I have to be granted with Administrator access to the organization to be able to retrieve its profile id? If this is the case, I can't implement it with the company lookup API because there is no way to be Administrator of other companies' profile. Any suggestions?